# Path for SqlServerIntegrationService not found, but does exists

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get Infos About SqlServerIntegrationService-details (Version etc.). I find the proper path to the file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.exe`, which really does exist, but still getting an `error: path could not be found`! I'm running the script as an admin and have definetly the proper Rights. What's wrong?

```
$mc = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer" $machine_name;
$mc.services | ? {($_.type -in ("SqlServer", "AnalysisServer", "ReportServer", 'SqlServerIntegrationService',"12") )} | 
% { 
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $const
$s = $_.name
if($_.ServiceState){$obj.status = $_.ServiceState}
if($_.ServiceAccount){$obj.serviceAccount = $_.ServiceAccount}
if($_.DisplayName){$obj.display_Name = $_.DisplayName}
if($_.Name){$obj.ServiceName = $_.Name}
##

if ($s.contains("$")) 
    {
        if($sqlListeners)
            {
                $instanz = $s.split('$')[1]
                foreach($sqlListener in $sqlListeners)
                {
                    if($instanz -eq $sqlListener.instanzName)
                    {
                        $sql_instance= "$($sqlListener.ServerName)\$($s.split('$')[1])"
                    }
                }
            }
        else
        {
            $sql_instance= "$($machine_name)\$($s.split('$')[1])"
        }
    } 
else 
    {
        $sql_instance=$machine_name
    } 
##
$obj.InstanceName = $sql_instance
$obj.Server = $machine_name
switch ($_.type) 
{
##

    'SqlServerIntegrationService' 
    {
        $pathname = ($mc.services[$s]).PathName;
        #$pathname= "\\$machine_name\" + ($pathname.replace(':\', '$\')).replace('"', '');
        try
        {
            $item=get-item $pathname
            [string]$ver= ($item.VersionInfo.ProductMajorPart).ToString() +'0';
            [string]$file_version = $item.VersionInfo.ProductVersion;

            #finding the SSIS edition by reading the registry
            $key="SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Microsoft SQL Server\$ver\Tools\Setup";
            $type = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine;
            $regkey=[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($type, $machine_name)
            $r=$regkey.OpenSubKey($key).GetValue('edition') 
            $obj.Edition = $r
            if($file_version){$obj.Version = $file_version.Split(".")[0]; $obj.patch_level = $file_version.Split(".")[2]}
            $obj.service_typ = "IS"
            $obj.ServiceName = $s
            $instInfo += $obj
        }
        catch
        {
            $obj.is_error = 1
            $obj.is_error_desc = [string]$Error[0].Exception.Message
            $obj.service_typ = "IS"
            $obj.ServiceName = $s
            $instInfo += $obj 
            continue
        }   

    } #sqlserverIntegrationService 

}#switch
$instInfo
```

The error occurs at the line: `$item=get-item $pathname`,
the real path (which does exists!) `is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\MsDtsSrvr.exe`.
I expect to populate the custom object with the Details of the DTS Service, but only getting: `path not found!`

Comment: Are you running powershell as Administrator, i was able to replicate the problem if not running as Administrator. possibly permissions

Comment: I'm definitely an admin.